# Monitoring progress of input stream in command line

Tags: java, inputstream, progress

I am reading a large text file from internet into string and I would like to display some sort of progress. Normally I would use *ProgressMonitorInputStream* but this program is running strictly in command line so this is not an option. Is there any easy way to get some sort of percentage, bytes remaining or any other kind of feedback? This is my code:

```
URL inUrl = new URL(*URL to be red*);
InputStream inStream=inUrl.openStream();
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
while(in.ready()){

    string=string+in.readLine();

}
in.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the file size using File.length method. or HttpConnection.getContentLength() if its Internet based resource.

in the while loop the percentage is

```
while(in.ready()){
    string = string +in.readLine();
    percentage = (string.length() / fileLength) * 100;
}
```

By the way its not a good practice to use

```
string + in.readLine()
```

Use a StringBuffer to this concatenation.

Comment: Also, I am really grateful for pointing out the StringBuffer object. It shortened the run time of program from 10 minutes to 10 seconds.